# Wrap content is not working on Vertical line in Relative Layout?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I am using View with a background colour to create a vertical line in a Relative layout . Wrap content is not working , the line is taking the entire viewport as height. Why is this happening ? attaching my code which is not working

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#f5f5f5"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:ignore="MissingPrefix">

 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <View
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="21.5dp"
        android:background="#a9382b" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/seeall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:textColor="#a9382b"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        tools:text="SEE ALL" />

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the height to `wrap_content` in this case simply will not work.

In general, `wrap_content` will give the view enough size to contain everything "inside" it (whether that's child views or just the text in a `TextView`, etc), but your `View` tag doesn't have anything "inside" it to define the height. In this case, it will grow to fill all available space.

If you want your `RelativeLayout` to be as tall as the `TextView` inside of it, and you want the line to go from top to bottom of *that* size, use the following for your `View` tag:

```
    <View
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/seeall"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/seeall"
        android:layout_marginLeft="21.5dp"
        android:background="#a9382b">
```

Comment: In fact, if you do this, it doesn't matter what value you set for `layout_height`; `match_parent`, `wrap_content`, and `0dp` will all work. `RelativeLayout` just sizes the `View` based on the constraints you pass below (the `layout_alignFoo` attrs).